# "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method," when using swing in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I know there are questions somewhat related to this issue, but those people don't have the same problem as I do here. Anyway below is my entire code, however only one line of it does not work. When I use the addActionListener method to find when the button named "btn" is clicked, the `btn.setText("testing 1 2 3")` gives the error as shown in this question's title. I'm not sure what it means and how to fix it.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class graphicsTestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("title here");
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JButton btn = new JButton("click");
        frame.getContentPane().add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                btn.setText("testing 1 2 3") //error is here
            }
        });      
    }
}
```

Please help! And thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the error message and then *search* for the error message. This is not a "new" problem.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code and it does work. Make sure that you don't have something else in your code. If your program only has this it does not make sense it gives this error

Comment: @VenelinK You're on Java 8, they're on Java 7.

Comment: wow just learned something new. I thought you'd have to add the class name graphicsTestClass before setting the text since the btn was hidden. Guess you don't have to in Java 8 anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `final` before `JButton`. You can not reach non-final and non-instance variables inside inner classes.

```
final JButton btn = new JButton("click");
```